# How to make og:image and og:title for Facebook refreshed

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, caching, meta

I want to make a website that if everyone pasted my URL in Facebook comments, my website show different `og:image` and `og:title` each comment.

I generated different `og:image` and `og:title` with PHP each I open my URL http://zeemays123.16mb.com/. Each I reload my website, the meta tag for `og:title` and `og:image` is changed. But not on Facebook.

I want something like this :

[image]

I tried to request post to facebook each page load with this script

```
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: 'http://zeemays123.16mb.com/',
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

But still not working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The tool is here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ I used it quite a time ago. To find it back I search Google with: "facebook dev graph refresh"

Comment: Image size matters! Minimum is 200x200 I guess.

Comment: As you can see, on my website images is 128x128, I still can show the image thumbnail on first comment, but not the next comment, Facebook chached it and show the same images

Comment: Forget that nonsense, it won’t work. Excessive re-scraping will get the URL blocked from further scrape attempts for a while. And changing the title is not possible any more after an item has received a certain amount of likes/shares, it will result in an "attempted frozen title change" error.